# Get updated state of component when calling method on class via enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can I get my test to reflect the new state of my component after calling updateItem on it. I did try rendered.update() but I must be missing on how something works. Thanks.

Method on class:

```
updateItem (id) {
    return updateItem(id)
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
            item: {blah:'blah'}
        });
    }, (error) => {
        throw error;
    });
}
```

Test:

```
it("should update item accordingly", () => {
    const rendered = shallow(React.createElement(Item));
    const result = rendered.instance().updateItem();
    expect(rendered.state('item')).toEqual({blah:'blah'});
})
```

Comment: I don't think it will work this way, how is function normally called in your component.

Comment: as a callback from child component

Comment: Ok but then you can get it from the child element props and call it.

Comment: Good call. I thought maybe there was still a way to do it this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the function from the childs prop and call it. As it returns a promise you need to use async/await or return the promise from your test, have a look at [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#content) for more infos. Then test the state of the rendered component.

```
it("should update item accordingly", async() => {
    const rendered = shallow(React.createElement(Item));
    await rendered.find('someChild).prop('updateItem')('someId')
    expect(item.state).toEqual({
      item: {blah:'blah'}
    })
})
```